# Set values of a column with numpy array

Tags: python, pandas

I have the issue that I would like to set all values for a given column using a numpy vector. Consider the following

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange
from scipy import random

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([arange(0,3), arange(10,15)], names=['A', 'B'])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['test'], index=index)
someValues = random.randint(0, 10, size=5)
df.loc[0,:]['test'] = someValues
print someValues
print df.loc[0,:]
```

The output is

```
Out[423]: array([9, 2, 7, 2, 4])
Out[422]: 
   test
B      
10  NaN
11  NaN
12  NaN
13  NaN
14  NaN
```

This comes - I guess - from me not providing the indices to the values. How can I do this operation, given that "the order" in which the values appear in the numpy array is going to be the order in which they should be set onto the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this, but since the right-hand-side (the assignee) is not labeled, it will just assign the first len(assignee) values

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from numpy import arange

In [3]: from scipy import random

In [4]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([arange(0,3), arange(10,15)], names=['A', 'B'])

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['test'], index=index)

In [6]: someValues = random.randint(0, 10, size=5)

In [8]: df.loc[0,'test'] = someValues

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
     test
A B      
0 10    0
  11    8
  12    2
  13    0
  14    2
1 10  NaN
  11  NaN
  12  NaN
  13  NaN
  14  NaN
2 10  NaN
  11  NaN
  12  NaN
  13  NaN
  14  NaN

[15 rows x 1 columns]
```

If you specify an index then it will assign the matching values.

```
In [34]: df.loc[:,'test'] = Series(someValues,index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0,10),(0,11),(1,10),(1,11),(1,14)]))

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
      test
A B       
0 10     5
  11     9
  12   NaN
  13   NaN
  14   NaN
1 10     1
  11     0
  12   NaN
  13   NaN
  14     7
2 10   NaN
  11   NaN
  12   NaN
  13   NaN
  14   NaN
```

Comment: **old comment deleted*** Setting via `df.loc[0, 'test']` seems to work, but `df.loc[0, :]` does not. When I print these, they look exactly the same. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I edited the post; but this IS on 0.13.1. The code reproduces exactly what is shown.

Comment: they are not exactly the same in the case of a multi-index, see the docs: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex.